# Minimum Sizes of BLOB and CBLOB

Tags: oracle, types, size

What is the minimum size occupied by CBLOB and BLOB data-types in ORACLE (for null value). Is it 1 byte like in for varchar?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to know?

Comment: I am thinking what is better: to add a column to a large table of type cblob which will be very rarely used, or to create another table for that cblob column. Want to know which solution is more space efficient

Comment: I do not think I would be concerned about space efficiency; I would think about it from a performance/ease point of view. I think I would use the separate table approach. BTW, the character large object is CLOB, not CBLOB.

Comment: http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2012/04/22/where-is-lob-data-stored/

Comment: @OldProgrammer I am still not getting direct answe how much space is occupied if the value is null. Is it 20 bytes?